# FlutterWebviewPlugin is throwing MissingPluginException

Tags: flutter

**code**

```
var flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
String url = "https://www.google.com";

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(url);
    ...
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
  flutter_webview_plugin: 0.0.9
```

Comment: Never write anything directly inside **Widget build**. It will be called everytime your view is updated. Instead use StatefulWidget and write those lines in initState()

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the blow code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.flutter_webview_plugin.WebviewActivity" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
```

Also after updating pubspec.yaml, run `flutter packages get`